# Is there a Linq to REST library for C#

Tags: c#, linq, rest

I have an Linq Expression and I want to convert it to a querystring for REST, i.e.

```
public IQueryable<Organisation> Organisations;

...
var organisations = Organisations.Where(x => x.Name == "Bob");
```

becomes

```
http://restservice.com/Organisations?$filter=Name eq "Bob"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did find one eventually in [Linq2Rest](https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest) (also [a NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/linq2rest)) which seems to fit the bill.  Doesn't support OAuth but would be possible to build this in.

Comment: the project site link is dead now. Looks like it's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

If you are control over the datasource, it's [OData](http://www.odata.org) what you are looking for.

A google-searched brought [HttpEntityClient](http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-System.Net.Http.HttpEntityClient) up, although I don't have any experience with it but it looks useful.

I guess you could also write your own implementation, because frankly, rest-apis don't have to follow a certain standard when it comes to filtering, ordering etc...

Answer (score 2):

[PocoHttp](https://github.com/PocoHttp/PocoHttp) can do exactly what you want. Moreover, it can do the call to the service and deserialize entities for you.

You can also easily modify its ODataProvider to support additional OData native functions (length, startswith, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Early pre-release versions of the OData Library had a query string parser, but expression building was never fully implemented, and the feature was then dropped. It's major hole in the library, since without it, you are left with payload and some header support only.

Fortunately [Linq2Rest](https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest) does exactly what you need, with one line of code:

```
var organisations = Organisations.sources.Filter(Request.Params).OfType<Organisations>()
```

The cast is necessary because a query string can select against the collection, producing a different collection of types. If you are only predicating on properties, then you don't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found that DataServiceContext developed by Microsoft works much smoother than Linq2Rest and HttpEntityClient third party libraries mentioned here. 
Documentation is also much better. The downside is that DataServiceContext works with XML only (no JSON). 
But both WebAPI OData REST services and WCF Data Services can return XML, if it requested by a client in HTTP header. Because XML support takes no additional development work, lack of JSON support is unlikely to be an issue.

There are LINQ to REST examples using DataServiceContext: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894039.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try [Odata](http://www.odata.org/)

The Open Data Protocol (OData) is a Web protocol for querying and updating data that provides a way to unlock your data and free it from silos that exist in applications today. OData does this by applying and building upon Web technologies such as HTTP, Atom Publishing Protocol (AtomPub) and JSON to provide access to information from a variety of applications, services, and stores. The protocol emerged from experiences implementing AtomPub clients and servers in a variety of products over the past several years.  OData is being used to expose and access information from a variety of sources including, but not limited to, relational databases, file systems, content management systems and traditional Web sites.

EDIT 1:
take a look at here also:
http://paulhammant.com/2012/02/13/client-side-mvc-frameworks-compared/